# Winapi : How do I for my button send different message according to the key pressed?

Tags: c++, winapi, button, keyboard

I created a button that, when clicked, will open an `.exe` file and close the current application:

```
HWND Button = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"Exe Application", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 500, 500, 200, 200, hWndParent, (HMENU)BUTTON_EXE, 0, 0);
```

And in the `WindProc`:

```
switch (uMsg)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case BUTTON_EXE:
            ShellExecute(hwnd, NULL, L"Module 1.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I want that when I click on the button with a key pressed (for example, <kbd>Shift</kbd>), the current application doesn't close.

So, I want that according to the key pressed when clicking the button, it sends a different message, but I didn't find how. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is a `"maj"` key? Or, do you mean the individual keys `m`, `a`, and `j`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a key is pressed while handling `WM_COMMAND` messages by calling the [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) function. Depending on its return value you can then implement different logic.

It's important to call `GetKeyState` (as opposed to [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)) to get the key state at the time the button was clicked.

Answer (score -2):

You can do additional processing of the message. For example:

1. your button will sent another message (WM_BUTTON_EXE_RAW).
2. you catch that message and resend other message (BUTTON_EXE) if button maj pressed only.